# how to show the .ppt file in the web page by the slide show manner

Tags: asp.net, flash, powerpoint

In my asp.net application,I want to show the .ppt file using the slide show manner.

That's to say,user can upload .ppt file to my server side,then other people can browser these ppts in the page ..

Since I have googled "embed powerpoint in web page" ,it seems that there is not a good idea to implement this and support the cross browser,so I thought the flash.

This is a slide show using the flash:
http://ajaxian.com/archives/prototype-and-jquery-a-code-comparison

What I want is show the contents of the .ppt in this manner(it would be better if it support the animations in the ppt)?

Is there any good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for "ppt to swf converter". There are a number of third party applications that can be run on the server to convert office documents into swf format. A lot of them include similar navigation controls to the SlideShare example.

Comment: Any recommendtion? There are some many search result,and I found many of the are apps which I can not use in the asp.net server side.

Comment: No sorry. My experience has been using these with LAMP. The other thing to consider is your budget. An open source technique is to use OpenOffice on the server for the conversion. Some suggestions in no particular order: Articulate, iSpring, Conaito, and PPT2Flash. Again most vendors offer free demo versions (with watermarked slides) for you to try before you buy.